# Read a string in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can anyone tell me why `console.log(data_)` is coming up as an empty/contents `undefined` object, in the following:

```
var test="10-Mar-15,54.21,54.56,54.05,54.34,969488";
chartFromLocal(test);        

function chartFromLocal(val)
{
    var data_=  d3.csv.parseRows(val,function( d){
        return d.map(function (d) {console.log(d)});
    });
    console.log(data_)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback function passed to `map` should return something. But you only do a `console.log`:

```
return d.map(function (d) {console.log(d)});
```

So, depending on what your intention is, replace the above by:

```
return d.map(function (d) { return do_something_with(d); });
```

If the only reason for doing the `map` was to log the content of each value in the console, then do:

```
function chartFromLocal(val)
{
    var data_=  d3.csv.parseRows(val);
    // debugging:
    data_.foreach(function(d){
        d.foreach(function (d) {console.log(d)});
    });
    console.log(data_);
}
```

Comment: I am doing more with the data. I was stuck trying to get that data out of `d.map()`. You solved it, Thanks.